# What job on freelancing websites can do a person with medium English level and lower medium knowledge of PC?

Tags: remote, working-from-home

A friend of mine is trying to make remote freelancing career. He cannot find job in his expertise for years because his job requires direct contact to the client (agriculture) and a remote advisory is not suitable in his case. Most people of his expertise are jobless in his wider area.

I advised his to try working remote jobs out of his field of expertise. He is eager learner and can quickly learn. But (!) his English is at the medium level (approx 2.5 of 5) and his knowledge of PC is around 2 of 5. He uses a regular office tools, but never tried using any advanced software like Photoshop. That's why I rate him 2, not because he's unable to learn and move to 3 or more.

What kind of jobs he can work in your opinion using websites like odesk or elance?

I first thought he could do horticulture (designing the look of gardens), but I could not find such jobs on these websites.

He cannot do email support as his English level is not yet at that level. I am also not sure about data entering or re-writing as he does not type as fast as a programmer (which is a good basis for re-writing skills).

Please do not disregard him as I am sure there are jobs for these types of people. I just cannot think of any as I do not have experience with such jobs (I am a developer).

PS. He tried learning programming, but he does not like it so it's not realistic that he can do any programming task. Also he does not have artistic abilities to become a designer.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe making things and selling them online (a la Etsy)?

Comment: @ChrisForrence I have not heard of Etsy. He can take a look. It only that we are located in Europe so not sure if this will work for Etsy (postage costs).

Comment: @ChrisForrence Also I would like that he starts career on odesk or elance to build his reputation and make a steady income. So my question refers to these websites particularly.

Comment: So no one has any ideas?

Comment: I've never used a freelancing website, so I'm striking out. Perhaps writing articles?

Comment: @ChrisForrence Writing means high level of English

Comment: Articles don't have to be English

Comment: @ChrisForrence True. But his language is neither Italian, Spanish, French or any Western language. And people from his language do not use freelancing sites but pay a little money hiring people locally.

Comment: Then, if I can ask, what is his native language?

Comment: Slavic, South-European

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to do any administrative tasks or be a remote personal assistant. First thing he should do is to improve his computer skills. There are so many people in need of a helping hand so he can be very useful to them and they don't need any very good English skills, average could do the work for them as long as he can understand and vice versa.

Comment: Personal assistant should have high level of English, right? Not sure if this is for him. What are administrative tasks - can you give a few examples on this?

Comment: Not necessarily. There are lots of admin jobs on odesk and elance like working on office doc or spreadsheet etc. They don't need high level of English.